# How do I change TortoiseHg default UI font?

Tags: user-interface, fonts, mercurial, tortoisehg

The default TortoiseHg / Hg Workbench UI font appears too small on a system running Win 11 Pro with ClearType disabled. Notably thinner and smaller than other applications.

I'm using TortoiseHg 6.2.3

I see from setting that I can set code windows text, but UI and branches/descriptions in log are still tiny and can't find a way to change them.
Is there some setting that I didn't see or does it have to be changed elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug](https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/tortoisehg/thg/-/issues/5323) (or missing feature) since atleast 2019.